# Failed to instantiate DiscoveryLocatorProperties in Spring-Cloud-Gateway with Spring Cloud Hoxton SR4

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway

Appreciate any help to sort out the below issue. I am using Spring Cloud Hoxton.SR4 and created a Gateway service with spring-cloud-starter-gateway. The application is throwing following exception in startup.

> ```sh
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'discoveryClientRouteDefinitionLocator' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/gateway/discovery/GatewayDiscoveryClientAutoConfiguration$ReactiveDiscoveryClientRouteDefinitionLocatorConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'discoveryClientRouteDefinitionLocator' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'discoveryLocatorProperties' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/gateway/discovery/GatewayDiscoveryClientAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.gateway.discovery.DiscoveryLocatorProperties]: Factory method 'discoveryLocatorProperties' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/ValidationException
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:798) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:539) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.gateway.discovery.DiscoveryLocatorProperties]: Factory method 'discoveryLocatorProperties' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/ValidationException
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
>     ... 39 common frames omitted
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/ValidationException
>     at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.discovery.GatewayDiscoveryClientAutoConfiguration.initPredicates(GatewayDiscoveryClientAutoConfiguration.java:61) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-core-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.discovery.GatewayDiscoveryClientAutoConfiguration.discoveryLocatorProperties(GatewayDiscoveryClientAutoConfiguration.java:86) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-core-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]enter code here
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoenter code hereke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
>     ... 40 common frames omitted
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.validation.ValidationException
>
>
>    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
>         at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
>     ... 47 common frames omitted>
> ```

I have put the following entries in application.properties  as well; but it is not resolving the issue

```
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.enabled=true
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.lower-case-service-id=true
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See this: [Spring Boot 2.3 Release Notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.3-Release-Notes#validation-starter-no-longer-included-in-web-starters)

It says:

> As of #19550, Web and WebFlux starters do not depend on the validation starter by default anymore. If your application is using validation features, you’ll need to manually add back a dependency on spring-boot-starter-validation in your build file.

The Spring Initializr doesn't seem to pick this up, so everyone is missing the validation starter for now.

Add the following to your POM in the `<dependencies>` block:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Here is the same issue on github, fyi
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/issues/1720